# angular pdf not working on IOS 10

Tags: angularjs, pdf, ios10, viewer

I have an ionic app using angular-pdf-viewer, with pdf.js , to display pdf documents from a url. The viewer works on android devices and IOS devices with IOS 9 but as on IOS 10 the pdf will not show. Anyone else had a similar problem ?

Comment: Somebody said safari detection in compatibility,js is not working anymore https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5405#issuecomment-252546051 and exposing safari's bug with range request. Try fixing the combatibility,js detection.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I tried to alter this line from the compatability.js file : if (isSafari || isOldAndroid || isChromeWithRangeBug) is now if (isOldAndroid || isChromeWithRangeBug) , so I dropped the check for Safari, but this is not working. Any tips as to what I should be fixing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually found that I needed to move this line out of the if statement so that it is always run: PDFJS.disableRange = true; It seems to all be working fine now for anyone experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Notice that you disabled range for all modern browsers that has no bugs in XHR with range requests (e.g. Chrome or Firefox). Having range requests allow you to load only portion needed for display of the PDF fast.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. And I found out it is PDFJS's compatability issue. Workaround for this issue is, you can set

```
PDFJS.disableRange = true;
```

i.e you are bounding to download the whole file instead in chunks without detecting the device.

Please comment someone else has still an issue, even after this workaround.